# To count every 3 rows to fit the condition by Pandas rolling

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe look like this:

```
raw_data ={'col0':[1,4,5,1,3,3,1,5,8,9,1,2]}
df = DataFrame(raw_data)
    col0
0      1
1      4
2      5
3      1
4      3
5      3
6      1
7      5
8      8
9      9
10     1
11     2
```

What I want to do is to count every 3 rows to fit condition(df['col0']>3) and make new col looks like this:

```
    col0 col_roll_count3
0      1  0  
1      4  1
2      5  2 #[index 0,1,2/ 4,5 fit the condition]
3      1  2
4      3  1
5      3  0 #[index 3,4,5/no fit the condition]
6      1  0
7      5  1
8      8  2
9      9  3
10     1  2
11     2  1
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried this but failed:

```
df['col_roll_count3'] = df[df['col0']>3].rolling(3).count()
print(df)

    col0  col1
0      1   NaN
1      4   1.0
2      5   2.0
3      1   NaN
4      3   NaN
5      3   NaN
6      1   NaN
7      5   3.0
8      8   3.0
9      9   3.0
10     1   NaN
11     2   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['col_roll_count3'] = df['col0'].gt(3).rolling(3).sum()
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `rolling`, `apply`, `np.count_nonzero`:

```
df['col_roll_count3'] = df.col0.rolling(3,min_periods=1)\
                          .apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x>3))
```

Output:

```
    col0  col_roll_count3
0      1              0.0
1      4              1.0
2      5              2.0
3      1              2.0
4      3              1.0
5      3              0.0
6      1              0.0
7      5              1.0
8      8              2.0
9      9              3.0
10     1              2.0
11     2              1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day.